# How to find all numbers in a string using Regex

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to extract all numbers from a string but I got the below code to work although it stops after the first match for 123.

```
String str = '123-456/7890';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)');
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );

if( m.find() ){
    system.debug( '-->>' + m.group() );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `matcher.find()` recursively until it returns false. Use a do/while block.

```
String str = '123-456/7890';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)');
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );

if(m.find()) {
  do {
    system.debug( '-->>' + m.group() );
  } while(m.find());
}
```

Comment: You can put while at the start, which avoids the need for if: `while(m.find()) { system.debug('-->>'+m.group()); }`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to separate all the numbers into separate strings you can do the following.

```
String numsplit = str.replaceAll('[^0-9]+', ';');
list<String> nums = numsplit.split(';');
```

If you also want to extract the other characters there is a built-in [splitbycharactertype](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_splitByCharacterType) method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Regex (?!^), this is called negative look ahead,

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

```
string abc = '123abc224aa33//11``45345';
string newstringwithjustnumbers='';
for(string s : abc.split('(?!^)')){
    if(s.isNumeric()){
        newstringwithjustnumbers = newstringwithjustnumbers+s;
    }
}
system.debug('@@@@@'+newstringwithjustnumbers);
```

Debug Log output :

> 10:45:01.244 (244625510)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[9]|System.debug(ANY)
>   10:45:01.244 (244660455)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|@@@@@123224331145345

Answer (score 2):

```
String input  = String.valueOf('20.02.001.X-M,!');

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('[^0-9]');

String numericOutput = p.matcher(input).replaceAll('');

//debug statement below will print 2002001

System.debug(numericOutput);
```