# Trying to get number of numbers in a string using regex

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have been trying to get the number of numbers in a string using regex, but without success. The following code returns me 0 groups in the expression.

```
String expression = '1 OR (2 OR 3) AND 4';
Matcher m = Pattern.compile('\\d').matcher(expression);
System.debug(m.groupCount());
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want the number of elements and, if possible, the value, so I can make this a map. Using the example provided, I would have a map like:

```
m.group(0) => 1
m.group(1) => 2
m.group(2) => 3
m.group(3) => 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on the first answer provided...

You'll likely want to change your pattern from **'\\d'** to **'\\d+'**
.   the reason is, if you get enough filters to hit more than 9 items, the matcher will interpret "10" as "1" and "0".  Changing your pattern to **'\\d+'** will correctly interpret "10" as "10".

Bonus> I've added a List to capture the integer values.

```
String expression  = '1 OR (2 OR 3) AND 4 OR 16';

pattern myPattern = pattern.compile('\\d+'); 
matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(expression);


List<Integer> myIntegers = new List<Integer>();

if(myMatcher.find()) {
  do {

        system.debug( '-->>' + myMatcher.group() );
        myIntegers.add(Integer.valueOf(myMatcher.group()));

  } while(myMatcher.find());

}
```

Helpful answer frm previous post: [How to find all numbers in a string using Regex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/how-to-find-all-numbers-in-a-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 3):

Uou can use `matcher.find()` to get all the numbers in loop. Hope this helps.

**Apex code**

```
String expression = '1 OR (2 OR 3) AND 4';
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)');
Matcher m = ptn.matcher(expression);

if(m.find()) {
  do {
    system.debug( '====' + m.group() );
  } while(m.find());
}
```